# Add hooks in a class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to do achieve a class-based approach to a plugin I'm currently developing but can't get my head around how to put the "mbf_page()" from within the class itself. Now I have put it put it outside the class just to make it work, but i want it to be a public function of the class. How would you do it?

```
<?php

    class Mediabank_Frontend {

      function __construct() {
         add_action('init', array($this, 'mbf_add_menu')); 
      }

      private function init() {
         $this->mbf_add_menu();
      }

      public function mbf_add_menu() {
          add_submenu_page('options-general.php', 'Mediabank settings', 'Mediabank', 
          'manage_options', 'mediabank-settings', 'mbf_page');
      }
}

function mbf_page() {
  echo '<div class="wrap"><h1>Settings</h1></div>';
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the function to the class? `public function mbf_page() {....}`

Comment: becasue i get this error if doing so: "Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'mbf_page' not found or invalid function name in"

Comment: I am not really a Wordpress developer, but i believe you have to use a static method then for that to work, so instead of just `public` you have to write `public static function mbf_page() {...}`, static methods cannot access `$this` and are only able to access other static methods and properties.
As for the `mbf_page` parameter, i think you'd need to pass a callback (not really sure), you can do that this way: `add_submenu_page(........, [static::class, 'mbf_page']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same way you're calling your `mbf_admin_menu` function. First move the `mbf_page()` function into the class as a `public function`, and then add it to the [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) callback argument as a callable function in the "array syntax": `array($this, 'mbf_page')`.

```
class Mediabank_Frontend {

    function __construct() {
        add_action('init', array($this, 'mbf_add_menu')); 
    }

    private function init() {
        $this->mbf_add_menu();
    }

    public function mbf_add_menu() {
        add_submenu_page('options-general.php', 'Mediabank settings', 'Mediabank', 'manage_options', 'mediabank-settings', array($this, 'mbf_add_menu') );
    }

    public function mbf_page() {
        echo '<div class="wrap"><h1>Settings</h1></div>';
    }
}
```

What `array($this, 'function_name')` tells WordPress (well, PHP) is to add the `function_name` from the **current class** instead of calling it from the globally available function scope.

You can pass callback functions in that array syntax, standard "function name" syntax, or even as a [Closure/Anonymous Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
add_submenu_page( 'parent', 'Title', 'Menu', 'cap', 'slug', 'function_name' ); // Get the globally available `function_name()` function.
add_submenu_page( 'parent', 'Title', 'Menu', 'cap', 'slug', array($this, 'function_name') ); // Get $CurrentClass->function_name() method
add_submenu_page( 'parent', 'Title', 'Menu', 'cap', 'slug', function(){ /* Do stuff */ return false; } ); // callback a defined-inline anonymous function
```